# sbt add plugin error

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

i've read all of the similar questions but neither of the suggestions fixes my problem. Perhaps i am unable to see it.

The problem is i have project/plugins.sbt
and when i try to add for example

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

it gives me

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: 
unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.11.2: not found
```

then i add

```
resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

but the error is same

my sbt version is

```
sbt launcher version 0.13.8
```

and scala version is

```
Scala code runner version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Perhaps someone can point me the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
when i put

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

to project/assembly.sbt
i got the same error

actually i do not think the error is for sbt-assembly
it gives the same sort of error when i try to add other plugins

```
[info] Resolving com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.13.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.13.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   .ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_0.13/0.13.0/sbt-assembly-0.13.0.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_0.13/0.13.0/sbt-assembly-0.13.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.13.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.13.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.13.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11) (assembly.sbt#L2-3)
1.0
```

EDIT

Ok for the others that are careless like me
in all the docs it says like project/plugins.sbt, or project/assembly.sbt, etc...
actualy i thought "**project**" should be the project folder of the application but it is the [your_project_name]/project :(
so all the mentioned conf should go in that directory.

thanks a lot for the replies..

Answer (score 0):

[sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly):

> For sbt 0.13.6+ add sbt-assembly as a dependency in
>   `project/assembly.sbt`:
>
> ```
> addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
> ```

Comment: 1) try to remove all occurrences of `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")` 2) remove the `resolvers += "sonatype-releases" ...` 3) or maybe try to clean your .ivy folder

Comment: it works when i remove them. btw i am using idea sbt plugin. when i refresh it just gives me the warning `[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:(2.11.1, 2.11.6)` but the code compiles with success

Comment: add `scalaVersion := "2.11.6"` to your `build.sbt` to avoid conflicts

Comment: IntelliJ sometimes caches multiple versions of the same libraries which may cause confusion during runtime. To clean those up go to "File -> Project Structure" in IntelliJ and manually delete any duplicated libraries you may have.

Comment: then try to clean your `.ivy2` folder from the different versions... that should eliminate the ambiguity, but you have to download all dependencies again: `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/*`. Or search manually for the ambiguous version in the `.ivy2/cache` and just delete that one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the version of the plugin you want to use?

Try this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

Comment: I see. Can you try to remove all our resolved from the build.sbt? Give it another try.

Comment: it works when i remove them. btw i am using idea sbt plugin. when i refresh it just gives me the warning [`warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:(2.11.1, 2.11.6)` but the code compiles with success